# Distinct not working

Tags: php, mysql

1.

```
select sub_category from add_skills where skillax_id='28'
```

2.

```
select distinct skillax_id from add_skills where sub_category in('Nutrition 101','All About Juicing','Make Up 101')
```

**above way distinct working but when m using...**

```
select distinct skillax_id from add_skills where sub_category in('".$na['sub_category']."')
```

**like this distinct not working**

3. ```
   select * from users where skillax_id in('28','23','5')
   ```

Comment: show your output where not producing distinct.

Comment: @nitul . . . Edit your question, providing same data and the results you are getting.  I can give you a hint:  `select distinct` does work.  Either you don't understand how it works, or something else in your query is not working.

Comment: just pick both 28 nituldas entries and place in notepad and check space junk character etc...

Comment: What about a group by ?

Comment: i used group by bt nt wrkng...

Comment: m gvng u the code ====================

Comment: define "not working" - do you get multiple (not distinct) results or is there a basic problem with the query? what do you get and what would you expect to get.

Comment: @Tarsis:- m getting duplicate data . I hv used distinct bt stl gtng duplicate data. i dnt want duplicate data.

Comment: @nital please use vowels and proper syntax. There are people in here trying to help you and your sms syntax doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

If there are ids in integer value then you can use implode function of php.
See below:

```
<?php
$query = "select distinct skillax_id from add_skills where sub_category in(".implode(",",$na['sub_category']).")";
?>
```

If there are string as category name then use below code for that.

```
<?php
$str = "";
if(!empty($na['sub_category']))
{
    foreach($na['sub_category'] as $key=>$val)
    {
        if($str == "")
            $str .= "'".$val."'";
        else
            $str .= ",'".$val."'";
    }
    $query = "select distinct skillax_id from add_skills where sub_category in(".$str.")";
}
?>
```

Comment: @nitul Can you please check again, by mistake i was wrote implode function instead of $str
if its not working then you can send me code on my mineshfriends@gmail.com

Comment: your code isn't working. But I have done by myself. So thank you so much for trying to help me. In future I will take help from you only.Thank you once again.